# What is the corresponding API in antlr4 for c#?

Tags: c#, java, antlr4

In the Antlr4 book, the author suggests a way to deal with keywords:

```
ID : [A-Za-z_]([A-Za-z_0-9])*

    if ( keywords.containsKey(getText().toUpperCase()) ) {
     setType(keywords.get(getText().toUpperCase())); // reset token type
    }
    }
   ;
```

however,this is invalid in C#. I tried to modify the codes:

```
     {
     if (keywords.ContainsKey(_localctx.GetText().ToUpper()))
     {
             _localctx. setType (keywords[_localctx.GetText().ToUpper()]); // reset token type
     }
```

All the methods except setType are available now, but I still don't know what is the method for "setType" in C#.

I am not familiar with Java, and I have got bored when trying to configure the IDE for Antlr4 in Java. However, C# requires only a installation of a plugin, but there isn't documentations for C#.

Comment: I think Type is a property, i.e. localctx.Type =...

Comment: Haven't you tried intellisense autocompletion?

Comment: @Onur, intellisense tells me there is only a GetType method. And when I set breakpoint at this place, the _localctx value is null.